# Proper way to update a Set element in a JPA @OneToMany relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, set

Lets assume we have a **bi-directional One-to-Many relationship** between Parent and Child.

I like the idea of model that relationship with a Set, because of it intrinsic nature of disallowing duplicates.

**Question:**
1) What would be the **proper JPA way** to update a child in such a situation?

- Query the Parent and pass an updated Child into it?
- Query the Child directly and just call its setters?

2) Has either way some **performance** advantages or disadvantages?

```
@Entity
public class Parent extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, ... )
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet();

    public void addChild( Child child ) { ... }
    public void removeChild( Child child ) { ... }

    // non-anemic domain model ?
    public void updateChild( Child child ) {
        // how to update the element in the Set?
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
How to properly write the update method? Since Sets in Java do not have a get method?

Comment: shouldn't make any difference you will feel regarding performance. the way depends on how your data is connected. but i think both is okay depending on what you want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update a `Child`, you don't need to operate the parent collection.

Thanks to the [dirty checking mechanism](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-hibernate-dirty-checking/), once the `Child` becomes managed in the currently running Persistence Context, every change is picked automatically and synchronized to the database.

That's the reason you don't have an `update` method in JPA. You only have [persist or merge](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persist-and-merge/) in `EntityManager`.

So, you need to do the following steps:

1. You load the `Child` by id:

   ```
   Child child = entityManager.find(Child.class, childId);
   ```
2. Do the changes on the `Child` and you are done:

   ```
   child.setName(newName);
   ```

Comment: Thanks Vlad for the infos!